# How to pass/type react-hook-form `setValue` to custom react hook (typescript)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

How can i pass `setValue` to a react hook?

I have a custom react hook, where I would like to set values in a form, by passing react-hook-form's `setValue`. However, since the migration from v6->v7 i can't for the life of me figure out the typing.

The hook looks like:

```
export function useUnselectOnChange(
  id: UUID,
  setValue: any // TODO: How to type this properly
  options?: Partial<UseUnselectOnChangeOptions>,
): void {
  const { current: optionsRef } = useRef<UseUnselectOnChangeOptions>({
    fallbackValue: ReorderEnum.Top,
    fieldName: 'place',
    ...options,
  });
  const previousUuid = useRef(id);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (previousUuid.current !== id) {
      setValue(optionsRef.fieldName, optionsRef.fallbackValue);
    }

    previousUuid.current = id;
  }, [id, setValue, optionsRef]);
}
```

Used like this:

```
useUnselectOnChange(id, setValue, {
  fallbackValue: '',
  fieldName: 'component',
});
```

Previously `setValue: UseFormMethods<Record<string, string>>['setValue']` worked but `UseFormMethods` does not exist  anymore.
I use `useFrom<FormValues>()` to get the form methods (`setValue` ++). This is how I do it in every component. `FormValues` is the where I specify the members and types of each form (so every `FormValues` is different). I can't figure out a generic typing in my hook that will accept `setValue`. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to use a generic and the `UseFormSetValue` type that your custom hook takes.
So it'll be

```
function customHook<T>(setValue:UseFormSetValue<T>){
  return []
}
```

then used like

```
const [] = customHook<IFormInput>(setValue)
```